# Is it possible to record phone calls via an Android App?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I'm a developer looking to create an Android application to record phone calls. This spawned out of my own personal need to record phone calls for my own purposes and for my records.

Is it possible to do this? Is it possible to get access to the microphone and what's coming through the speaker?

I'm kind of new to Android development, so bear with me :) I assume that I could probably record into WAV and then at the end of the call, transcode it into MP3 using LAME or something. This may kill the battery, but this seems like a good project for me to get used to Android with. I'm looking to use Android 2.X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. The telephony stack is fairly restrictive to application developers, partly for security reasons.

You might be to write your own "Phone app", perhaps based off the [default one](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Phone.git;a=tree), and include the necessary hooks to intercept the audio streams.

However, this would be an extremely difficult project if you are new to Android development. I would suggest trying out some other projects first, before looking into the telephony stuff.