# Record Communication outgoing and incoming call in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I want to record communication of 
incoming as well as outgoing calls.
Will anyone help me ?
Any related answers will be appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Record phone calls on android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370278/record-phone-calls-on-android-phone) or [Is it possible to record phone calls via an Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283208/is-it-possible-to-record-phone-calls-via-an-android-app)