# Is it possible to record calls both sides(mic,speaker) in android?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, voice-recording, android-mediaplayer

i'm trying to develop an application to record calls bothside(mic and speaker). I've seen there is one app vrecorder providing this vrecorder for android 1.6. 
Now i want to do this for android 2.2 and above. Can i know is this possible with  `MediaRecorder.AudioSource`.
I've read some forums they are saying that there are some issues on doing this. 
In Stackoverflow itself several questions are about record voice calls saying that not posible. But these posts are older. [Is it possible to record phone calls via an Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283208/is-it-possible-to-record-phone-calls-via-an-android-app) .
But http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117  in this discussion they are saying that some issues are there but we can implement.
Atlast, please I need some descriptive answers, that can we record voice calls in android both way (from mic and speaker).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call recording is not yet possible on Android. The [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226) you are referencing is still not resolved.

People that have been able to do call recording use rooted phones with custom kernel.

On stock Android phones, you can only record your voice from microphone, but you can not record the sound of the other party. If you only want to record your voice use android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC

Comment: But there one more app providing the same feature. recording voice both sides.
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androglobe.androrec&feature=search_result. this application is recently updated. I've installed and tested in my mobile it is working fine sounds good. recording both sides but the voice of other end is in low pitch.

Comment: I agree with @atluriajith. Probably there are unofficial tricks to fix it.