# Is there a way to record calls in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-sdk-2.3, phone-call

Is there a way to write an app which records phone calls in android via android-sdk?
so that you can store phonecalls as .wav or something else?

I like to write something like a dictaphone.
Do you think, there is a chance to make this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283208/is-it-possible-to-record-phone-calls-via-an-android-app

Comment: Have you tried [this?](http://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&nord=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=android%20record%20%20call&pbx=1&oq=android%20record%20%20call&aq=f&aqi=g1g-c2g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=30l258872l0l259264l17l13l0l3l3l2l251l1814l3.9.1l15l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9048a0ef92486a5a&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=785)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I record voice and record Call in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194342/how-can-i-record-voice-and-record-call-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Android does not allow you to record the audio stream due to legal terms.

However due to buggy hardware implementations it is possible, on some devices, to record the audio stream.