# MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL not working

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, call-recording

I am going to create a program that recording voice call but `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` does not work. I think its not support on many phones.

I'm trying with `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` but it just records and upload voice. In another word record my voice on microphone!!!

And I'm trying with `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION` but it has a bad sound.

Here is my sample code:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.reset();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
try {
  recorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.e("LOG", "prepare() failed");
}
recorder.start();
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: For the security reason, you can not do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283208/is-it-possible-to-record-phone-calls-via-an-android-app